# Trouble with nested templates having same root node name

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have an issue where the root node and child node have same names in the output .xml file which had to be formatted with XSLT for grouping issue.
The data of the XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA_DS>
<P_SVC_ID>NMW</P_SVC_ID>
<P_BUS_UNIT>NMWSC</P_BUS_UNIT>
<P_END_DATE>2016-01-16T08:00:00.000+00:00</P_END_DATE>
<LOGO><!--Generated by Oracle BI Publisher 11.1.1.7.0-->
<Properties>
<IMG_DIR_PATH>images</IMG_DIR_PATH>
<IMGFILECAL>CWSCO.jpg</IMGFILECAL>
<IMGFILEHW>HWSCO.jpg</IMGFILEHW>
<IMGFILENM>NMWSC.jpg</IMGFILENM>
</Properties>
</LOGO>
<DATA_DS>
<G_2>
<RPTDEF>Report shows account balance of all customers under
30 60 90 or over 90 days old summarized
by AR balance per district
</RPTDEF>
</G_2>
<G_1>
<ENTITY_NAME>Aaron,M </ENTITY_NAME>
<ACCT_ID>08638132256</ACCT_ID>
<SA_ID>08638224515</SA_ID>
<CM_DISTRICT>CG</CM_DISTRICT>
<SA_BAL_CURRENT>0</SA_BAL_CURRENT>
<SA_BAL_31_60>0</SA_BAL_31_60>
<SA_BAL_61_90>0</SA_BAL_61_90>
<SA_BAL_OVER_90>0</SA_BAL_OVER_90>
<TOT_AMT>0</TOT_AMT>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<ENTITY_NAME>Madhu</ENTITY_NAME>
<ACCT_ID>8649446fr121</ACCT_ID>
<SA_ID>86494463rf41</SA_ID>
<CM_DISTRICT>CG</CM_DISTRICT>
<SA_BAL_CURRENT>0</SA_BAL_CURRENT>
<SA_BAL_31_60>0</SA_BAL_31_60>
<SA_BAL_61_90>0</SA_BAL_61_90>
<SA_BAL_OVER_90>0</SA_BAL_OVER_90>
<TOT_AMT>0</TOT_AMT>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<ENTITY_NAME>dCruz,Jared </ENTITY_NAME>
<ACCT_ID>748607238507</ACCT_ID>
<SA_ID>748607238446</SA_ID>
<CM_DISTRICT>WWA</CM_DISTRICT>
<SA_BAL_CURRENT>0</SA_BAL_CURRENT>
<SA_BAL_31_60>0</SA_BAL_31_60>
<SA_BAL_61_90>0</SA_BAL_61_90>
<SA_BAL_OVER_90>0</SA_BAL_OVER_90>
<TOT_AMT>0</TOT_AMT>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<ENTITY_NAME>d Sa6s,Geneva </ENTITY_NAME>
<ACCT_ID>803581432479</ACCT_ID>
<SA_ID>803581434216</SA_ID>
<CM_DISTRICT>WWA</CM_DISTRICT>
<SA_BAL_CURRENT>0</SA_BAL_CURRENT>
<SA_BAL_31_60>0</SA_BAL_31_60>
<SA_BAL_61_90>0</SA_BAL_61_90>
<SA_BAL_OVER_90>0</SA_BAL_OVER_90>
<TOT_AMT>0</TOT_AMT>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>
</DATA_DS>
```

================================================== =======
Am trying to bring all elements but G_1 should be grouped on CM_DISTRICT values such as
CA.....
So all CA value CM_DISTRICT are grouped under this element.

===============================================
I have been using the following XSL code:
================================================== ==

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="DATA_DS" match="DATA_DS" use="DATA_DS"/>
<xsl:template match="DATA_DS">
<xsl:for-each select="DATA_DS">
<xsl:element name="DATA_DS">
<xsl:element name="P_SVC_ID"><xsl:value-of select="//P_SVC_ID" /></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="P_BUS_UNIT"><xsl:value-of select="//P_BUS_UNIT"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="P_END_DATE"><xsl:value-of select="//P_END_DATE"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="LOGO">
<xsl:element name="Properties">
<xsl:element name="IMG_DIR_PATH"><xsl:value-of select="//IMG_DIR_PATH"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="IMGFILECAL"><xsl:value-of select="//IMGFILECAL"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="IMGFILEHW"><xsl:value-of select="//IMGFILEHW"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="IMGFILENM"><xsl:value-of select="//IMGFILENM"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:key name="groups" match="DATA_DS/DATA_DS/G_1/CM_DISTRICT" use="."/>
<xsl:template match="/DATA_DS/DATA_DS">
<DATA_DS>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/DATA_DS/DATA_DS/G_1/CM_DISTRICT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', .)[1])]"/>
</DATA_DS>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DATA_DS/DATA_DS/G_1/CM_DISTRICT">
<xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="."/>
<CM_DISTRICT>
<xsl:value-of select="$currentGroup"/>

<xsl:for-each select="key('groups', $currentGroup)">
<G_1>
<ACCT_ID>
<xsl:value-of select="../ACCT_ID"/>
</ACCT_ID>
<ENTITY_NAME>
<xsl:value-of select="../ENTITY_NAME"/>
</ENTITY_NAME>
</G_1>
</xsl:for-each>
</CM_DISTRICT>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

================================================== ==
I had separately achieved the grouping of this code as below with perfect results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:key name="groups" match="DATA_DS/DATA_DS/G_1/CM_DISTRICT" use="."/>
<xsl:template match="/DATA_DS/DATA_DS">
<DATA_DS>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/DATA_DS/DATA_DS/G_1/CM_DISTRICT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', .)[1])]"/>
</DATA_DS>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DATA_DS/DATA_DS/G_1/CM_DISTRICT">
<xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="."/>
<CM_DISTRICT>
<xsl:value-of select="$currentGroup"/>

<xsl:for-each select="key('groups', $currentGroup)">
<G_1>
<ACCT_ID>
<xsl:value-of select="../ACCT_ID"/>
</ACCT_ID>
<ENTITY_NAME>
<xsl:value-of select="../ENTITY_NAME"/>
</ENTITY_NAME>
</G_1>
</xsl:for-each>
</CM_DISTRICT>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This brings the output correctly for ....  but the rest of it is ignored..

But when i try to merge this code with the elements for  till child node  is included, it just brings the first result set only.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), as that will take care of copying all the other nodes you don't need to modify, but wish to keep

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

   <xsl:key match="G_1" name="groups" use="CM_DISTRICT"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/DATA_DS/DATA_DS">
      <DATA_DS>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="G_1[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', CM_DISTRICT)[1])]"/>
      </DATA_DS>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="G_1">
      <xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="CM_DISTRICT"/>
      <CM_DISTRICT>
         <xsl:value-of select="$currentGroup"/>

         <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', $currentGroup)">
            <G_1>
               <ACCT_ID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ACCT_ID"/>
               </ACCT_ID>
               <ENTITY_NAME>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ENTITY_NAME"/>
               </ENTITY_NAME>
            </G_1>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </CM_DISTRICT>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have simplified your key to `<xsl:key match="G_1" name="groups" use="CM_DISTRICT"/>` as it arguably fits better with your requirement to group `G_1` elements by `CM_DISTRICT`.

Also note you don't need to specify a full path to the `G_1` element in the template match (You would only need to do so if you had `G_1` elements in other parts of the XML that you didn't want to group).